# Loading javascript import into React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Edit**

I decided to try adding the script tags to the index.html file and conditionally rendering them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $show_stuff = 'no';
    var $add_stuff = 'yes';
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://www.example.com/includes.php?stuff=true';
    document.getElementById('feed').appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Then in the component I want the feed to show up I did this,

```
<div id="credit-feed" />
```

I also tried conditionally rendering the script tag in the index.html file like this,

```
if(window.location.href === "localhost:3000/my/path" ) { script tag... }
```

These both do not work as well. The script tag does not show up in the div in the first example and the second does show the script tag but it does not render.

But, when I add the script tag like normal to the head of the HTML file, the feed renders as I would expect.

**Background**

We do business with a company that provides us a Javascript script tag which appends the data from it's response into the body of our web page. We have had a PHP site for the past 8 years without problems but now that we are switching to React, we can not figure out the correct way to use this tag in the component it will live.

**Problem**

When we add the script tag to the React component, it does not append the correct data to the page. In fact it does not append any data to the page.

**Example**

I have tried to load the script tag like normal,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">      
  var $somevar = "false";
  var $addjquery = "yes";      
  </script>
   <script 
          type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/do/deef.php?feedtype=all ">
    </script>
```

Another way I have tried in the React component,

```
  componentWillMount() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    const $somevar = 'false';
    const $addjquery = 'yes';

    script.src = 'https://www.example.com/get/feed.php?&data=all';
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

**Question**

What is the correct way to load the script tag so it will append the data to my application?

Comment: Why do you have $somevar (and also misspelled $somvar) and $addjquery? It's kind of confusing to me. What do you mean by "appends the data from its response into the body of our web page"? You need to first identify if you're referencing the script correctly. If the script is running correctly, what is it trying to do exactly?

Comment: Well the vars are values that are defined which the script response that comes back will change depending on what those values are set to. by append I mean that the response is appended to the body of the page. So basically the data that comes back from the response of the script will magically appear in the body part of the web page. Also, to clarify this is not something that has a bug in it. This is simply a matter of how do you do something in React that is not in the documentation.

Comment: Is there a way you can set up a jsbin or jsfiddle where we can see the problem? jsbin has React, so it shouldn't be too hard to set up an example.

Answer (score 0):

Usually with a React app, you will have an index.html file that contains the React component. You should put the `<script>` reference inside the html file. So I would definitely use the first approach you mention. If it's not loading, can you check the browser inspector and find out what kind of error you are getting? For one thing, you should remove the empty white space from the URL. That could be the issue.